# ¿Por qué Pandas no encuentra un index que sí existe?

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy usando pandas para ordenar un dataFrame. La idea es obtener los valores de una columna (TRACK_ID) con valores específicos de otra columna (TRACK_DURATION). El código funciona para la mayoría de los valores que ordeno (usando `.loc`), pero de vez en cuando me arroja el error: `KeyError: 'the label [0.599] is not in the [index]'`

My data frame es asi:

```
df
Out[51]: 
    Unnamed: 0  TRACK_ID  TRACK_DURATION  TRACK_DISPLACEMENT
0            0         2           0.559               0.066
1           28       673           0.559               0.132
2           19       465           0.559               0.206
3           27       660           0.602               0.187
4           21       479           0.602               0.497
5           17       440           0.602               0.351
6           29       725           0.602               0.059
7           10       324           0.602               0.112
8           30       782           0.602               0.412
9            7       152           0.602               0.308
10           2        49           0.602               0.048
11           1        14           0.645               0.051
12          15       401           0.688               0.391
13          11       331           0.731               0.173
14          26       608           0.731               0.579
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/SMT analysis codes/Sort.csv')

df1 = df.set_index(['TRACK_DURATION'])

sets = df1.loc[0.599, 'TRACK_ID']   

M = sets.values.tolist()
```

En este caso, si uso `0.559` obtengo el error, pero si cambio a `0.602` no hay ningún problema.Es muy claro que el index SI existe, pero pandas no lo encuentra. Alguna idea de porque pasa esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede parecerte claro que esas etiquetas existen pero en realidad no lo es. La columna `TRACK_DURATION` es de tipo float64 y un float está sujeto a imprecisión tanto por su naturaleza (numeros irracionales por ejemplo) como por su representación en formato de punto flotante en binario. Esto hace que donde tu ves 0.599 en realidad su representación sea 0.5899999999....

Dada esta característica. Tienes varias opciones:

- Pasar la columna a tipo cadena (str). Claro que esto no es lo ideal ya que perdemos capacidad de cálculo.
- Usar `ix` o `loc` pero pasando un rango adecuado:

  ```
  import pandas as pd


  df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/SMT analysis codes/Sort.csv')

  df1 = df.set_index(['TRACK_DURATION'])
  sets = df1.loc[0.558:0.559, 'TRACK_ID']   
  M = sets.values.tolist()
  ```

  Funciona pero es terriblemente feo y poco universal.
- Usar [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), mucho más portable y evitar reindexar:

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np

  df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/SMT analysis codes/Sort.csv')
  M = df[np.isclose(df['TRACK_DURATION'], 0.559)]['TRACK_ID'].tolist()
  ```

Lo mejor es evitar indices en forma de floats porque son esencialmente ambiguos e imprecisos.

Los dos ejemplos anteriores dan de salida:

```
>>> M    
[2, 673, 465]
```

Afirmas que deseas ordenar el dataframe, no se cual es la utilidad de lo que intentas pero si especificaras como quieres ordenarlo a lo mejor sería posible ayudarte. Pandas ofrece mucho potencial a la hora de ordenar y agrupar datos, es posible que te estes complicando sin necesidad.

Comment: Ohh `np.isclose` es nuevo para mi. Muchas gracias, parece que eso de los números floats es algo que necesito estudiar mas a fondo. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @JonathanPacheco  realmente es algo que ocasiona muchos pero que muchos errores difíciles de encontrar. Por eso es importante conocerlos, en especial la representación en punto flotante. Busca 'coma flotante' o 'floating point representation' en Google, es muy importante conocer esto para un programador. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

El archivo track.csv no contiene ninguna fila con
TRACK_DURATION 0.599

```
python  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  

df = pd.read_csv('AnacondaProjects/track.csv')  
df1 = df.set_index(['TRACK_DURATION'])  
try:  
    sets = df1.loc[0.599, 'TRACK_ID']   
    M = sets.values.tolist()  
    print(M)  
except:  
    print('No existe un track con esa duracion')
```

Salida:

```
No existe un track con esa duracion
```

---

El archivo track1.csv tiene agregado 3 filas con TRACK_DURATION 0.599 y TRACK_ID: [101,102,103]

Por lo tanto, el programa que propones funciona bien se le puede poner una excepción con try para el caso que no exista el valor TRACK_DURATION

```
python  
df = pd.read_csv('AnacondaProjects/track1.csv')  
df1 = df.set_index(['TRACK_DURATION'])  
sets = df1.loc[0.599, 'TRACK_ID']   
M = sets.values.tolist()  
print(M)
```

Salida:

```
[101, 102, 103]
```